# Iterate Through a List Given a Starting Point

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, iteration

Say you have a list, and you are given a starting point (for example the 3rd index). How would you iterate over the list starting at that index, and loop back around to visit all of the elements of the list? Meaning, you can start your iteration in the middle of the list but once you reach the end you would continue from the beginning until every element in the list has been visited. What is the cleanest and most efficient way to do something like this? Ideally, I'm looking for something effective to a python pseudo `for x in list starting with i:` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is large and you want to avoid copying parts of the list, then you need to use a custom iterator:

```
def starting_with(arr, start_index):
     # use xrange instead of range in python 2
     for i in range(start_index, len(arr)):
        yield arr[i]
     for i in range(start_index):
        yield arr[i]

for value in starting_with(my_list, 3):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to go back around (without itertools) you have to use the remainder of division operator:

```
i = start_index
while i < len(mylist) + start_index:
    print mylist[i % len(mylist)]
    i+=1
```

Or even better, as pointed out by @jonrsharpe:

```
for idx in range(len(mylist)):
     print  mylist[(idx + start_index) % len(mylist)]
```

For the sake of completeness, and because the generator will be more efficient in this case, as suggested by @Régis B., you can:

```
def mygen(lst, start):
    for idx in range(len(lst)):
        yield  lst[(idx + start) % len(lst)]
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use something like `for index in range(len(mylist)): print mylist[(index + start_index) % len(mylist)]`, rather than a `while` loop.

Comment: @rll I doubt it was downvoted because of that... Probably because of `i++`, which you quickly removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own iterator function that does this very handily (and efficiently), as shown below.

It's important to note that, as written, you can pass it a negative index, to which the length of the list is effective added to, so `-2` would mean the the second to the last item in a list — which is exactly how Python itself normally handles list negative indices.

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:  # Python 3
    xrange = range

def starting_with(start_index, seq):
    if start_index > 0:
        start_index = start_index-len(seq)
    for i in xrange(start_index, len(seq)+start_index):
        yield seq[i]

for value in starting_with(3, my_list):
    ...
```